# jquery slide up menu asp.net

Tags: jquery, css

i make an open menu in jquery i want the default status is closed but it didn't work 
its only worked when i make the div display :block at the beginning but i want the beginning status to be closed

html :

```
<div class="menu">
    <div>
        <div class="menu_header" id="A1" status="close"><a href="#"><img src="img/insert.jpg" id="B1" alt="" align="left" />header</a></div>
        <div  class="menu_body" style="display:none;" id="A11"><a href="#">samy</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*click function starts here*/
        $('.menu_header').click(function () {
            var s = $(this).attr('id');
            var divid = $("#" + s + "1").attr('id');
            var imgid = $("#" + s + " a img").attr('id');
            var imgsrc = $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src');
var status = $(this).attr('status');
            if (status == "close") {
                $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src', 'img/remove.jpg');
                $(this).attr('status', 'open');
                $("#" + divid).attr("style", "display: block !important");
                $(this).attr('status', 'open');
                $("#" + s + "1").slideDown(800);


            }
            else if (status == "open") {
                $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src', 'img/insert.jpg');
                $("#" + imgid + "").css('display', 'none');
                $("#" + divid).attr("style", "display: block !important");
                $(this).attr('status', 'close');
                $("#" + s + "1").slideUp(800);

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

css :

```
.menu{width:300px;margin-top:1px;height:auto;}
.menu_header a{color:#faf6e0;padding-top:8px;height:40px;width:100%;display:block;padding-left:10px;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #548975), color-stop(1, #37705a));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);}
.menu_header img{margin:1px;}
.menu_header a:hover{cursor:point;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #37705a), color-stop(1, #548975));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #37705a 5%, #548975 100%);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #37705a 5%, #548975 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #37705a 5%, #548975 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #37705a 5%, #548975 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #37705a 5%, #548975 100%);}
.menu_body a{padding-top:1px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;color:#5f5f5f;vertical-align:middle;height:30px;width:100%;background: #faf6e0 ;border:1px #d9c074 solid; cursor:pointer !important;}
.menu_body a:hover{background: #e7d6a1; color:#5f5f5f;border-left: 5px #e86a6a solid;padding-left:15px; cursor:pointer;}
```

plz i want help as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JS and let me know if works.

Here is the running fiddle : [http://jsfiddle.net/bw5Luug4/](http://jsfiddle.net/bw5Luug4/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*click function starts here*/
        $('.menu_header').click(function () {
            var s = $(this).attr('id');
            var divid = $("#" + s + "1").attr('id');
            var imgid = $("#" + s + " a img").attr('id');
            var imgsrc = $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src');
            var status = $(this).attr('status');

            if (status == "close") {
                $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src', 'img/remove.jpg');
                $(this).attr('status', 'open'); 
                $("#" + s + "1").slideDown(800); 

            }
            else if (status == "open") {
                $("#" + imgid + "").attr('src', 'img/insert.jpg'); 
                $(this).attr('status', 'close');
                 $("#" + s + "1").slideUp(800);
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: its worked but please can u give me a little description about the problem

Comment: You do not have to specify display attribute as slideDown and slideUp animations can handle that for you, for more description- http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/ and http://api.jquery.com/slideup/